# Prove: $na_0x^{n-1}+(n-1)a_1x^{n-2}+...+a_{n-1}=0$ has at least one positive root smaller than $x_0$

Tags: polynomials

Let $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}x=0$ has a positive root $x=x_0$.

Prove: $na_0x^{n-1}+(n-1)a_1x^{n-2}+...+a_{n-1}=0$ has at least one positive root smaller than $x_0$

Vieta's theorem on $na_0x^{n-1}+(n-1)a_1x^{n-2}+...+a_{n-1}=0$,

$x_1+x_2+...+x_{n-1}=\frac{(n-1)a_1}{na_0}$

$x_1x_2...x_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{a_{n-1}}{na_0}$

How to evaluate Vieta's formulas for $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}x=0$

Are Vieta's formulas useful for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the second polynomial is the derivative of the first and that the first polynomial has two zeros: $0$ and $x_0$. The statement follows from [Rolle's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem) which states that between two zeros of $f(x)$ there is a zero of $f^\prime(x)$.

Comment: Is there an approach in abstract algebra?

Comment: It is unlikely that there is a pure-algebra approach, as this fact relies on the continuity of the real line. It will fail if we work on a general field. For example, $x^3-x$ has a root $x=1$ over $\mathbb Q$, but its derivative $3x^2-1$ does not have any.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can use **Rolle's Theorem**:

If a real-valued function $f$ is continuous on a proper closed interval $[a, b]$, differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, and $f(a)=f(b)$, then there exists at least one $c$ in the open interval (a, b) such that $f'(c)=0$.

Let $$f(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n−1}+...+a_{n−1}x.$$ Obviously, we have $f(0)=0$ and $f(x_0)=0$ due to the assumption. Then, use Rolle's Theorem, here $a$ is $0$ and $b$ is $x_0$, so there must exist at least one $x_1$ in the $(0,x_0)$ such that $f'(x_1)=0.$

Firstly, we can claim that $x_1$ is a positive number that is smaller than $x_0$. Secondly, $$f'(x)=na_0x^{n−1}+(n−1)a_1x^{n−2}+...+a_{n−1},$$ and $f'(x_1)$ shows that $x_1$ is the solution of the formula $$na_0x^{n−1}+(n−1)a_1x^{n−2}+...+a_{n−1}=0.$$

This completes the proof.

If you are not familiar with **Rolle's Theorem** and want to take an deep look inside its proof, you can refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem.